# for each loop is duplicating in sales order part

Tags: vb.net, foreach-loop-container

I have 2 for each statement. 1 is to get order and another one is to get the order details.

I have 2 orders and each order got 1 order details.

When i get the data from another application and do insert into my database , it returns 1 order with 2 order details.

so in total in my database instead of total of 2 order details I have 4, which is duplicating.

```
***The result I want :
My Order :
#WHFT1100
#WHFT1101

My OrderDetails :
#WHFT1101   0   0       1278    FG-CHIC-0007    BBQ CHICKEN 500GMS
#WHFT1100   0   0       1278    FG-CHIC-0007    BBQ CHICKEN 500GMS

But what I'm getting inserted into database now is :

My Order :
#WHFT1100
#WHFT1101

My OrderDetails :
#WHFT1101   0   0       1278    FG-CHIC-0007    BBQ CHICKEN 500GMS
#WHFT1100   0   0       1278    FG-CHIC-0007    BBQ CHICKEN 500GMS
#WHFT1101   0   0       1278    FG-CHIC-0007    BBQ CHICKEN 500GMS
#WHFT1100   0   0       1278    FG-CHIC-0007    BBQ CHICKEN 500GMS
```

This is my code (the duplicating is happening in sales order part):

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("RefNo", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("OrderDate", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("TotalAmt", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("TotalDisc", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Email", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("OrderNum", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("TotalTax", GetType(Double))
    dt.Columns.Add("TotalWeight", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Remarks", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("ShipCode", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("ShipPrice", GetType(Double))
    dt.Columns.Add("SAddress", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("SName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("STel", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("SCity", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("SPostCode", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("SState", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("SCountry", GetType(String))

 For Each obj In st.orders
     Dim RefNo As Long = obj.id
     Dim OrderDate As String = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.created_at).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
     Dim TotalAmt As Double = obj.total_price
     Dim TotalDisc As Double = obj.total_discounts
     Dim Email As String = obj.email
     Dim OrderNum As String = obj.name 'Order Name
     Dim TotalTax As Double = obj.total_tax
     Dim TotalWeight As Long = obj.total_weight
     Dim Remarks As String = obj.note
     Dim FirstName As String = ""
     Dim LastName As String = ""
     Dim ShipCode As String = ""
     Dim ShipPrice As Double
     If obj.customer IsNot Nothing Then
         FirstName = obj.customer.first_name
         LastName = obj.customer.last_name
     End If
     If obj.shipping_lines.Count > 0 And obj.shipping_lines IsNot Nothing Then
         ShipCode = obj.shipping_lines(0).title
         ShipPrice = obj.shipping_lines(0).price
     End If
     Dim SAddress As String = ""
     Dim SName As String = ""
     Dim STel As String = ""
     Dim SCity As String = ""
     Dim SPostCode As String = ""
     Dim SState As String = ""
     Dim SCountry As String = ""
     If obj.shipping_address IsNot Nothing Then
         SAddress = obj.shipping_address.address1
         SName = obj.shipping_address.first_name
         STel = obj.shipping_address.phone
         SCity = obj.shipping_address.city
         SPostCode = obj.shipping_address.zip
         SState = obj.shipping_address.province
         SCountry = obj.shipping_address.country
     End If
     dt.Rows.Add(RefNo, OrderDate, TotalAmt, TotalDisc, Email, OrderNum, TotalTax, TotalWeight, Remarks, FirstName, LastName, ShipCode, ShipPrice, SAddress, SName, STel, SCity, SPostCode, SState, SCountry)
 Next
 'datatable2 to insert record for list of products details from line_items
 Dim dt2 As DataTable = New DataTable()
 dt2.Columns.Add("RefNo", GetType(String))
 dt2.Columns.Add("LineID", GetType(String))
 dt2.Columns.Add("Title", GetType(String))
 dt2.Columns.Add("ProductID", GetType(String))
 dt2.Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Integer))
 dt2.Columns.Add("Grams", GetType(Double))
 dt2.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Double))
 dt2.Columns.Add("SKU", GetType(String))
 For Each obj In st.orders
     For Each lineitems In obj.line_items
         Dim RefNo As Long = obj.id
         Dim LineID As Long
         Dim Title As String = ""
         Dim ProductID As Long
         Dim Quantity As Integer
         Dim Grams As Double
         Dim Price As Double
         Dim SKU As String = ""
         If obj.line_items IsNot Nothing Then
             LineID = lineitems.id
             Title = lineitems.title
             ProductID = lineitems.product_id
             Quantity = lineitems.quantity
             Grams = lineitems.grams
             Price = lineitems.price
             SKU = lineitems.sku
         End If
         dt2.Rows.Add(RefNo, LineID, Title, ProductID, Quantity, Grams, Price, SKU)
     Next
 Next
 'POST SALES ORDER TO EMAC
 Dim SOID1 As Integer
 Dim OrderDate1 As Date
 Dim UpdatedDate As Date
 Dim OrderNum1 As String = ""
 Dim SOCustCode As String = "300-ONLINE"
 'Post Sales Order to allocated shops db to save in tblSalesOrder and SalesOrderDetail
    
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
     'Get db connection for each branch
     Dim mDbsName As String = "WH_PCH"
     'check if the sales order number already exist in emac (if exist exit)
     Dim dataConn2 As SqlConnection = DBConnectionHelper.GetDataConn(mDbsName)
     Dim CountRefNo As Integer
     dataConn2.Open()
     Dim tsql2 As String = "SELECT Count(RefNo) From tblSalesOrder where RefNo =@RefNo"
     Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(tsql2, dataConn2)
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefNo", row("OrderNum"))
         CountRefNo = command.ExecuteScalar
         'If record not exist then insert into tblSIOrder
         If CountRefNo = 0 Then
             Dim dataConn As SqlConnection = DBConnectionHelper.GetDataConn(mDbsName)
             Dim ComBranchID As Integer = 1
             dataConn.Open()
             'Insert Statement
             Using transaction As SqlTransaction = dataConn.BeginTransaction
                 Try
                     'Sales Order
                     Dim sqlStr As String = "EXEC USP_InsertSalesOrder @SOID,@RefNo,@SODate
                     Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlStr, dataConn, transaction)
                     sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear()
                     sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SOID", "0"))
                     sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RefNo", row("OrderNum")))
                     sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SODate", row("OrderDate")))
                        
                     OrderDate1 = row("OrderDate")
                     UpdatedDate = row("OrderDate")
                     OrderNum1 = row("OrderNum")
                     ' Execute
                     Dim sqlDR As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
                     If sqlDR.Read() Then
                         SOID1 = sqlDR(0)
                     End If
                     sqlDR.Close()
                     sqlCmd.Dispose()
                     transaction.Commit()
                     'Sales Order Part
                     For Each row2 As DataRow In dt2.Rows
                         Using transaction2 As SqlTransaction = dataConn.BeginTransaction
                             Try
                                    
                                 'sql
                                 Dim sql2 As String = "EXEC USP_InsertSalesOrderPart @SOPID,@SOID,@SORefNo
                                 Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand
                                 cmd2 = New SqlCommand(sql2, dataConn) With {.Transaction = transaction2}
                                 cmd2.Parameters.Clear()
                                 cmd2.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SOPID", 0))
                                 cmd2.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SOID", SOID1))
                                 cmd2.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SORefNo", OrderNum1))
                                 ' Execute
                                 Dim sqlDR1 As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
                                 sqlDR1.Close()
                                 cmd2.Dispose()
                                 transaction2.Commit()
                             Catch ex As Exception
                                 transaction2.Rollback()
                                 dataConn.Close()
                                 Exit Sub
                             End Try
                         End Using
                     Next
                 Catch ex As Exception
                     transaction.Rollback()
                     dataConn.Close()
                     Exit Sub
                 End Try
             End Using
             dataConn.Close()
         End If
     End Using
     dataConn2.Close()
 Next
```

Comment: For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows .... For Each row2 As DataRow In dt2.Rows ...... EXEC USP_InsertSalesOrder...  next .... next. 2 rows in dt, 2 rows in dt2 will result in 4 rows in USP_InsertSalesOrder. Select only corresponding lines. In the creation of DT2 you take obj.line_items only. DT and DT2 are copies of the database data. This selection should be done again, I think.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am not sure how u trying to give me the solution. How to write the code?

Comment: I'm not a database programmer, I cannot give code. I used to work with databases on AS400!!!

Comment: do you have an order number in DT and DT2? If so add an if dt.orderns = dt2.ordernr after the line: For Each row2 As DataRow In dt2.Rows

Comment: yes both DT and DT2 has this order num #WHFT1100
#WHFT1101

Comment: add the  dt.ordernr = dt2.ordernr. You know the exact naming of the fields. Success